# Bukkit Java - ArrayList is not working in Event

Tags: java, bukkit, spigot

I want to make a plugin which gives a player night vision efect after typing a command and it is working but i also want to add if player is on this arraylist its giving an efect after dying, but it looks like after EventHandler its not loading players from arraylist.

```
public class Gamma implements CommandExecutor, Listener {

    private ArrayList<Player> gammaList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        PotionEffect potionEffect = player.getPotionEffect(PotionEffectType.NIGHT_VISION);
        if (gammaList.contains(player)) {
            gammaList.remove(player);
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Pomyslnie" + ChatColor.RED + " usunieto" + ChatColor.GREEN + " efekt gammy!");
            player.removePotionEffect(PotionEffectType.NIGHT_VISION);
        } else if (!gammaList.contains(player)) {
            gammaList.add(player);
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Pomyslnie" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + " nadano" + ChatColor.GREEN + " efekt gammy!");
            player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.NIGHT_VISION, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1));
        }
        return true;
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerDie(EntityResurrectEvent event) {
        
        Player player = (Player) event.getEntity();
        if (gammaList.contains(player)) {
            player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.NIGHT_VISION, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Sb know what should I change in this code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have zero experience with bukkit or spigot from a developer point of view, but given my Java experience: You're defining your `ArrayList` non-`static`, that means that it most likely isn't unique throughout the server and means that every instance of your class might have its own `ArrayList`. Your approach would only work if your `Game` class is a singleton.

You can circumvent this by making the reference to the List `static` and also use a thread-safe list, like the [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

So something like:

```
private static List<Player> gammaList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
```

should work.

Comment: A better solution here imo would be to not register two separate instances of the same class when it can be avoided. It's a frequent mistake to see (pseudo) `registerListener(new Gamma());` and `registerCommands(new Gamma());` right next to each other. These should instead be the same variable, passed to both methods. `static` is primarily a memory tool, not an access/organizational one.

Comment: (Granted the DV might be a little harsh given that it's an appropriate _Java_ answer, but less of an appropriate _Bukkit_ answer, where plugin management mixed with static fields and plugin classloaders may cause very unexpected bugs).

Comment: It's been a prolific problem in community-submitted code since Bukkit's inception (static and class unloads/loads), and is strongly (strongly) discouraged. The DV is meant more for discouraging someone coming through google to use this approach (or at least read the comments to see more)